How can I return an empty list from FunctionCompile?
The following code is for solving a linear congruence of the form $ax=b \; (\mathrm{mod}\ m)$ using FunctionCompile.
h = FunctionCompile[
  Function[{Typed[a, "Integer128"], Typed[b, "Integer128"], Typed[m, "Integer128"]},
   Module[{g},
    g = GCD[a, m];
    If[Mod[b, g] == 0,
     {Mod[ModularInverse[Quotient[a, g], Quotient[m, g]]*Quotient[b, g], 
       Quotient[m, g]]}, {}]]], TargetSystem -> {"MacOSX-ARM64"}]

Running this and comparing with SolveValues, I get:
a = 12; b = 3; m = 3^4;

SolveValues[a x == b, x, Modulus -> m]
(* {7, 34, 61} *)

h[a, b, m]
(* {7} *)

All good apart from the fact I am just, obviously, reporting the first solution.
However, if I modify the function as in
h = FunctionCompile[
  Function[{Typed[a, "Integer128"], Typed[b, "Integer128"], Typed[m, "Integer128"]},
   Module[{g},
    g = GCD[a, m];
    If[Mod[b, g] == 0,
     Range[Mod[ModularInverse[Quotient[a, g], Quotient[m, g]]*
        Quotient[b, g], Quotient[m, g]], m - 1, 
       Quotient[m, g]], {}]]], TargetSystem -> {"MacOSX-ARM64"}]

to return a list of the solutions à la SolveValues, I run into the following problem

TypeError. For the function Native`ListNullary no matching candidate
that takes zero arguments and returns type PackedArray[Integer128,
1:Integer64] was found.

It obviously doesn't like a list created by Range being returned.
Now I am quite clueless on this but does anyone know how to return a list in this situation. Note the reason I am not using Compile is that I need numbers larger than $MachineInteger and FunctionCompile allows Integer128 to be used.
EDIT:
My problem isn't as stated above the output of Range if I change the type to Integer64 (it seems Integer128 is not supported by Range) - BUT it is the returning of {} from the If statement that really bothers me.
How can I return {}?
I could simply return say {-1}, but this routine feeds into many other routines and changing all those is no small task as I am expecting an empty list as the no solution output.

Why do you need your own compiled function when SolveValues does the job and even much faster?

@azerbajdzan Because this compiled version is about 200 times faster than SolveValues which is very slow.

There are several things to unpack here.
How can I return an empty list?
Let's try the simplest possible example:
FunctionCompile[Function[{}]]
(* FunctionCompile::err1: Function definition of Native`ListNullary has a resolved type
   with free variables. *)

This looks unpromising! Why is it not possible to return a simple empty list?! Well, when compiling a function, we suddenly have to deal with types of expressions. Given certain arguments, a compiled function must always return the data of same type. But what is the type of {}? An error message gives us a hint that the type of {} is Native`ListNullary. What is this type?
CompilerInformation[Native`ListNullary]


It's a type parametrized by v1 that is then converted to either "ListExpression"::[v1] or "ListVector"::[v1]. This means that you cannot create an empty list without specifying what the type of its elements are! You can do this either with Typed:
FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[{}, "ListVector"::["Integer64"]]]]
(* CompiledCodeFunction[{} -> "ListVector"["Integer64"]] *)

or by forcingly casting it with Cast to some other list-like type, such as "PackedArray":
FunctionCompile[Function[Cast[{}, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]]]
(* CompiledCodeFunction[{} -> "PackedArray"["Real64", 1]] *)

Note that the trick with Range[1, 0] also returns a packed array:
TypeOf[Range[1, 0]]
(* "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1] *)

Why doesn't Range like "Integer128"?
Let's take a look at information about Range:
CompilerInformation[Range]


You can see that Range always returns a "PackedArray", for which (as stated in the documentation):

Only elements that have a type of "MachineInteger", "Real64" or "ComplexReal64" can be stored in a "PackedArray".

Note that "MachineInteger" is "Integer64" on 64-bit machines. Therefore, if you want to return a list of "Integer128", you cannot do it with Range. But you can build up your own "ListVector" (or any list-like structure, such as LinkedList):
FunctionCompile[Function[Range[2^65, 2^65 + 10]]]
(* FunctionCompile::err1. ... is out of range for a constant with type Integer64. *)

FunctionCompile[Function[Table[i, {i, 2^65, 2^65 + 10}]]][]
(* CompiledCodeFunction::uncomp. A compiled code runtime error occurred; 
   reverting to uncompiled evaluation: IteratorLengthError. *)

FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[a, "Integer128"], Typed[b, "Integer128"]}, 
  Module[{list = {}}, Do[AppendTo[list, i], {i, a, b}]; list]]]
(* CompiledCodeFunction[{"Integer128", "Integer128"} -> "ListVector"["Integer128"]] *)

%[2^65, 2^65 + 10]
(* {36893488147419103232, ..., 36893488147419103242} *)

Fixing your code
h = FunctionCompile[
  Function[{Typed[a, "Integer128"], Typed[b, "Integer128"], Typed[m, "Integer128"]}, 
   Module[{g = GCD[a, m], res = {}},
    If[Mod[b, g] == 0, 
     Do[AppendTo[res, i], {i, 
       Mod[ModularInverse[Quotient[a, g], Quotient[m, g]]*
         Quotient[b, g], Quotient[m, g]], m - 1, Quotient[m, g]}]];
    res
    ]]]
(* CompiledCodeFunction[{"Integer128", "Integer128", "Integer128"} -> 
   "ListVector"["Integer128"]] *)

h[12, 3, 3^4]
(* {7, 34, 61} *)


Thanks for the detailed reply. Much to chew on here - busy day today but I'll reply later when I've got the chance. Much appreciated.

I have accepted your answer. The AppendTo does slow things down considerably so I replaced that with a linked list - though that is not exactly fast either. Can't use Reap/Sow in a FunctionCompile or InternalBag either.

Replacing "Integer128" with "Integer64" and {} with Range[1, 0] in If statement works for me. (I also use a different operating system which should be replace with your own.)
I am not sure why Range[1, 0] is accepted while {} not.
h = FunctionCompile[
  Function[{Typed[a, "Integer64"], Typed[b, "Integer64"], 
    Typed[m, "Integer64"]}, Module[{g}, g = GCD[a, m];
    If[Mod[b, g] == 0, 
     Range[Mod[
       ModularInverse[Quotient[a, g], Quotient[m, g]]*Quotient[b, g], 
       Quotient[m, g]], m - 1, Quotient[m, g]], Range[1, 0]]]], 
  TargetSystem -> {"Windows-x86-64"}]

Here the first case with solutions and second case without solution.
h[12, 3, 3^4]
h[3, 8, 9]


{7, 34, 61}

{}


Genius. I tried lots of methods of producing a {} and they all gave problems. Very puzzling why that particular version works but the other methods of giving {} did not. Much appreciated.

If it answers your question you can accept the answer.
